# Overload operator << print backwards

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was overloaded the two operators: operator<< and operator++

operator<<

```
ArithmeticSequence & ArithmeticSequence::operator++()
{
    this->lastElement += goToNext;
    this->sum += lastElement;

    return *this;
}
```

operator++

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const ArithmeticSequence as)
{
    out << as.sum;
    return out;
}
```

now the main is:

```
ArithmeticSequence AS(1.3, 2.5);
cout << "++AS sum: " << ++AS << " ++AS sum: " << ++AS << endl;
```

output:

```
++AS sum: 20.2 ++AS sum: 11.4
```

the correct output need to be:

```
++AS sum: 11.4 ++AS sum: 20.2
```

why the output is revers?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Comment: Note: Not the order of << is unspecified, but the order of the two `++AS` calls

Answer (score 0):

There's no sequence point in between your two `++A5` so they can be evaluated in any order.

This will work as expected:

```
 cout << "++AS sum: " << ++AS;
 cout << " ++AS sum: " << ++AS << endl;
```